# Attempt to refuse all connections except one domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I've been trying for some hours block all connection except my domain in *httpd config.* but I'm not able to connect with my own domain. I just get *Forbidden* page.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName Server-VM
DocumentRoot /var/www/
    SetEnvIf Referer domain\.cc internal
    <FilesMatch "\.(avi|mp4)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=internal
   </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

My Apache version: 2.2.15
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

Try

```
<FilesMatch "\.(avi|mp4)$">
   Require host domain.cc
</FilesMatch>
```

More info from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html